# Volume emission without texture when using UV coordinates

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, volumetrics, emission

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HhavlMLV6k) tutorial for creating laser beams in Blender, but I can't get the Noise Texture to work as the Emission strength.

When I plug the Emission output into the surface input, the noise texture shows up.
[image: Noise Texture shows up as surface]

But when I plug the emission into the volume, the texture dissapears
[image: Noise texture does not show up as volume]

I have also tried using a Principled Volume Shader, but with the same result. I might have accidentally pressed a button while fiddling around, but I have no idea what button that could have been.

Also when I use e.g. the Object Coordinates, everything works fine. But sadly I need the UV Coordinates in order to animate the texture.

Comment: No, volumetrics do not, can not, use UV coordinates.  I think you'll find generated coordinates are fine for what you want to do, possibly with a bit of mapping.

Comment: What a bummer. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Bruh.. You connected output of color ramp to the color input of the emission. Obviously the noise texture will appear as the color. If you want to use noise texture as emission strength, then connect the output of color ramp to strength of emission node

Comment: @Maulik Sharma Connecting Emission BSDF to Volume output isn't wrong; it creates an emissive volume which is perfect for flames, lasers, fluorescent gases, etc.

Comment: My bad. Sorry :(